# Using sed in ksh script with condition

Tags: shell, sed, ksh

I'm using a sed command for replacing some words in text files. This command is embedded in a ksh script.
I would like to reach that not everytime will every replacement rule of sed fire, only if some conditions are filled. E.g. depending on a value of a shell variable.

In other words I would like to write this script without the if statement, I would rather include the conditional expression inside the sed. Is it possible?

```
REPLACE_A=TRUE

if [ "$REPLACE_A" = "TRUE" ]
then
    cat myfile \
    | sed 's/A/B/g;
          's/C/D/g;
          's/E/F/g;'
else
    cat myfile \
    | sed 's/C/D/g;
          's/E/F/g;'    
fi
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to apply a condition like that inside sed, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I agree with @EdoDodo -- I don't think it's possible: `sed` is a fine stream editor, but doesn't do conditionals.  And why would you want to make your `ksh` script *less* readable.

Comment: I have a very long list of words to replace. I just don't want to list them several times, if a new condition has to be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that pops into my mind is to store the `sed` command in a variable, like

```
# in your script
SEDCMD=""
# ...
SEDCMD="s/A/B/g;"
# later 
SEDCMD="${SEDCMD}s/C/D/g;"
# ...
# finally
sed "$SEDCMD" FILE
```

But it still not the solution you want.

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted, but it suits me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with sed, but with awk. If you like to try, I suggest you have a look at this:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html